# Select Id(s) using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco

I have a `DynamicNode` named products which has product name and  product id. 
I need to select all products id's to a array from the `DynamicNode` products using LINQ.

I tried something like

```
 @helper PrintProductYearChart(IEnumerable<DynamicNode> products)
{

    var res = products.select(x => x.filelds['Id']).ToAarray();
}
```

but its not working correctly.

Can any one help.Thanks in advance

Comment: How do the actual and the expected answer differ?

Comment: in the products.select and x.fields['Id'] having error.Can't resolve the symbol

Comment: What does the public interface of `DynamicNode` look like?

Comment: What type of information do you need from me.you clarify above comment ?

Comment: What is `DynamicNode` defined like? What properties and methods does it have? (Only with that knowledge, we can tell what `filelds` does or what to use instead.)

Comment: Also, is it really `filelds` (in capital letters: `FILELDS`) or `fileIds` (in capital letters: `FILEIDS`)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The  `Select` LINQ  operator Projects each element of a sequence into a new form. what you are you doing will project only one element with 'Id' as index  so  it will return one element only not an array of  Id's

here you should  specifiy that  you want the ID

```
   @helper PrintProductYearChart(IEnumerable<DynamicNode> products)
    {

        var res = products.select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new List<DynamicNode>(){
            new DynamicNode { Id = "1", Name = "name1"},
            new DynamicNode { Id = "2", Name = "name2"}
        };

        //Getting Ids using extension methods and lambda expressions
        string[] Ids = collection.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();

        foreach (string id in Ids)
            Console.WriteLine(id);

        //Gettings ids using linq expression
        var linqIds = from s in collection
                           select s.Id;
        string[] lIds = linqIds.ToArray();

        foreach (string id in lIds)
            Console.WriteLine(id);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class DynamicNode
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```